# Oracle Data Integrator: Update a Variable

Tags: oracle, etl, oracle-data-integrator

Is there a way to update a variable throughout the whole ETL?

I have an ETL that runs Scenarios and after the Scenario Runs I would like it to populate a variable with the step that was just completed…

1. Scenario 1

   a.IF Completed, True Variable gets Scenario 1 False Variable is blank

   b.IF Failed, False Variable gets Scenario 1 True Variable is blank
2. Etc…

So at the end I will have a True variable with Scenario 1, Scenario 2, Scenario 4, Scenario 6

And a False variable with Scenario 3, Scenario 5, Scenario 7

And the final email will say something like:

Scenario 1, Scenario 2, Scenario 4, Scenario 6 Finished successfully

Scenario 3, Scenario 5, Scenario 7 Failed to complete.

Doable?

Answer (score 0):

Doable

You don't really need all those variables. Create the email basing on an sql query extracting the scenario run statuses from ODI work repository